# Syntax Error in XMLHttpRequest Function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm not primarily JS, so I may be making a stupid here, apologies if that is the case.

In the code:

```
function loadeightoheightclap("http://thomasmurphydesign.com/dubstepclap.wav") {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', "http://thomasmurphydesign.com/dubstepclap.wav", true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        eightoheightclapbuffer = buffer;
    }, onError);
}
request.send();
}
```

The URL in that's the argument of function loadeightoheightclap is throwing a syntax error. It's a valid URL, and there's no syntax error when that URL is used as an argument of request.open later.

How do I need to modify the argument to remove the error?

Comment: Remove the argument to remove the error. And read up on JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions definitions should take a parameter name, not an actual value:

```
function loadeightoheightclap(url) { /* ... */ }
```

Your should only use a value when *calling* it:

```
loadeightoheightclap("http://thomasmurphydesign.com/dubstepclap.wav");
```

Then you can use that value by name inside the function:

```
request.open('GET', url, true);
```

Comment: Thank you bfavaretto. I was mistaking the code in the tutorial I was working through for a placeholder in which I was to paste the URL.